# Draw custom lines on chart

Tags: c#, jquery

I've a requirement,

Generate a line chart, then user must be able to draw custom lines on the chart and save the chart with newly added lines. I prefer to use High chart or Google chart for generating the chart, but I couldn't find a solution for drawing custom line on the chart. Is there any way to accomplish my requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Both Highcharts/Google charts generate SVG content so if you want to draw on top of the chart you will have to manipulate the SVG DOM manually - I would recommend using [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) for your custom drawing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i have managed to draw custom lines in HighChart itself.